# How to install tkinter for python3.8 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8, apt

I am using `sudo apt-get install -y python3-tk python3.8-tk` to install tkinter, but Python keeps giving me a **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'".**

I have read all the similar questions, but I did not found any proper solution so far. It should be possible to install tkinter from anywhere without rebuilding it from source, shouldn't it?

For reproduction, here is my exact setup:

- minimal GitHub repository: [https://github.com/LinqLover/test-python-ci-tkinter](https://github.com/LinqLover/test-python-ci-tkinter/tree/234479284708be8b9e3d95c6bf88af19c35d0ef7)
- the relevant GitHub CI log: https://github.com/LinqLover/test-python-ci-tkinter/runs/1779242524?check_suite_focus=true

I'd be thankful for any tip. I also wanted to create an issue, but apparently, there is no separate python repository for tkinter with an issue tracker.

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Mahrad Hanaforoosh ubuntu-18.04

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use this command:

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y python3-tk
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, [it still fails with the same error message.](https://github.com/LinqLover/test-python-ci-tkinter/runs/3795405493?check_suite_focus=true)